# Swift - How to update object in multi-dimensional directory

Tags: arrays, swift, macos

I want to be able to find and update a custom object in an array of these objects. The challenge is that the custom objects also can be children of the object.

The custom object looks like this:

```
class CustomObject: NSObject {
    var id: String?
    var title: String?
    var childObjects: [CustomObject]?
}
```

I would like to be able to create a function that overwrites the custom object with fx a specific ID, like this:

```
 var allCustomObjects: [CustomObject]?
    
 func updateCustomObject(withId id: String, newCustomObject: CustomObject) {
        
     var updatedAllCustomObjects = allCustomObjects
        
     // ...
     // find and update the specific custom object with the id
     // ...
        
     allCustomObjects = updatedAllCustomObjects
 }
```

I recognize this must be a pretty normal issue regarding multidimensional arrays / directories in both Swift and other languages. Please let me know what normal practice is used for this issue.

Comment: I'm assuming the ids are unique in the entire tree of `CustomObject`s? For every given ID, there is exactly one `CustomObject`, somewhere in the tree, with that ID? (As opposed to unique only within an object's siblings)

Comment: I think the more _swift like_ and probably easier way to achieve such an algorithm is to add a recursive method like `update(at id: String)` that could return a boolean (did it work ?) or a CustomObject? (either one was affected or not). With this you start considering `CustomObject` as a tree which seems to fit your use case. I probably can't provide good example as I didn't practice swift for years, but looking at BTree could be a good start https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree

Comment: @Sweeper the ids are always unique in this example, yes.

Comment: @Zyigh I see. This function would then contain a loop to call the same function of the childObjects and go deeper into the tree?

Comment: Are all child objects also in `allCustomObjects`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most things to do with trees, recursion is going to help. You can add an extra parameter that indicates which array of `CustomObject`s that you are currently going through, and returns a `Bool` indicating whether the ID is found, for short-circuiting purposes.

```
@discardableResult
func updateCustomObject(withId id: String, in objectsOrNil: inout [CustomObject]?, newCustomObject: CustomObject) -> Bool {
    guard let objects = objectsOrNil else { return false }
    if let index = objects.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id }) {
        // base case: if we can find the ID directly in the array passed in
        objectsOrNil?[index] = newCustomObject
        return true
    } else { 
        // recursive case: we need to do the same thing for the children of
        // each of the objects in the array
        for obj in objects {
            // if an update is successful, we can end the loop there!
            if updateCustomObject(withId: id, in: &obj.childObjects, newCustomObject: newCustomObject) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
        // technically I think you can also replace the loop with a call to "contains":
        // return objects.contains(where: { 
        //     updateCustomObject(withId: id, in: &$0.childObjects, newCustomObject: newCustomObject) 
        //  })
        // but I don't like doing that because updateCustomObject has side effects
    }
}
```

You would call this like this, with the `in:` parameter being `allCustomObjects`.

```
updateCustomObject(withId: "...", in: &allCustomObjects, newCustomObject: ...)
```